# How to hide Chrome on Android password suggestion ribbon on regular inputs

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

**Chrome on Android is showing a password suggestion ribbon for unrelated inputs and I can't find any way to hide it.**

I have a form with multiple inputs (created in React). All of them are of type `"text"`, `"date"`, `"number"` or other non-login form related type. Each one of them has both attributes `autocomplete="off"` and `aria-autocomplete="none"`. The surrounding form has those attributes as well.

No matter what I do, this password ribbon appears on Chrome for Android. *(Chrome version 103.0.5060.70, running on Android 10)* and I can't seem to find any information about it online. No settings or experimental flags in Chrome to disable it, no HTML attributes which prompt it to be shown nor attributes to hide it.

**The ribbon causes two problems**:

1. **The UX problem**: Obviously, I don't want users to get password suggestions for completely unrelated inputs.
2. **The Layout problem**: The bottom sheet shown in the image is positioned with `bottom: 0`, and the password ribbon disappears (not visually but from the layout) for less than 50 milliseconds, causing an abrupt jump. *(This I could get around by manually positioning the bottom sheet to the bottom of the page with `top: {window.innerHeight}px` and animating that property using Framer motion with a delay of 50ms.*

**Can anyone tell me anything about this password ribbon?**

- How to hide it?
- Why is it shown?
- Is there a setting in Chrome, or a flag in `chrome://flags/` to disable it?

(See below for image of app and the password ribbon showing on an unrelated text input.)

[Image of the Ribbon in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeMr0.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Android keyboard in Chrome from showing password management on HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988591/prevent-android-keyboard-in-chrome-from-showing-password-management-on-html-inpu)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Chrome bug. See duplicate ([Prevent Android keyboard in Chrome from showing password management on HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988591/prevent-android-keyboard-in-chrome-from-showing-password-management-on-html-inpu))

The workaround is to set `type="search"` on your input.

Comment: Thank you! This works but only to an extent. On mobile this changes the input submit button to a search icon, and disables switching focus to the next form input on submit. Additionally, you cannot use this with numeric inputs. Sadly, in my case, these are too large drawbacks for now.