# What is making the password autofill bar show above the keyboard in Android Chrome?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, ime, password-autofill

About a week ago I noticed that Android Chrome was showing a password autofill bar above the keyboard in my app ([Parchment](https://iplayif.com/?story=https://ifarchive.org/if-archive/games/zcode/Savoir-Faire.zblorb)). The HTML for the `<input>` is the following, which is definitely not a password input:

```
<input aria-hidden="false" autocapitalize="off" class="Input LineInput" type="text" maxlength="120">
```

Does anyone know what would make Chrome think that the password autofill bar should be displayed, and what can be done to stop it happening?

[image: Screenshot from Parchment in Android Chrome showing the password autofill bar]

Comment: I might be saying the obvious, but have you tried setting `autocomplete` to false? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#disabling_autocompletion

Comment: @MauriceLam Setting `autocomplete="off"` doesn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: is the input inside of a form?

Comment: @Hermanboxcar No it's just a stand alone input box.

Answer (score 3):

This problem exists for a whole range of input types. I tested and confirmed it's an issue for `type="text"`, `type="number"`, `type="password"`, `type="tel"`, `type="url"`, `type="email"`

The only type not affected is `type="search"`

Depending on your application, it may or may not be possible to switch to a search input. For me, it made sense as it was a search of sorts.

I've given a more detailed response on [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988591/prevent-android-keyboard-in-chrome-from-showing-password-management-on-html-inpu/73466347#73466347)

Answer (score -1):

If the input is inside of the form, put and attr on the form that is `autocomplete="off"`, then make a hidden input as the first child of that form, with also `autocomplete="off"` If it doesn't work, then try doing `autocomplete="chrome-off"`