# Prevent input suggestion on MS Edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge is displaying an annoying pop-out with the text "*results from saved info*" when I start typing something (e.g. 'te') into the input. I want to hide this (for all users) so I have set `autocomplete=off` but I still see this annoying box. I've also tried `list="autocompleteOff"` and disabling all extensions with no success.

[image]

Sandbox reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-golick-2fnlnt?file=/index.html

```
<input id="input-guess" 
                    type="text"
                    bind:value={guess} 
                    spellcheck="true" 
                    placeholder={$t('common.enter_a_word')}
                    autocomplete="off" 
                    list="autocompleteOff" />
```

Comment: Hey, I'm unable to replicate the error. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that works more off-the-bat, so it's easier to diagnose the error?

Comment: I think it's dependent on the browser history of the client so that might be tricky. I've posted an example sandbox. I've also found out the feature is called 'autofill' and can be disabled by the client but I've still not found an html attribute to prevent it.

Comment: I had to turn on autofill, create a from that points to itself, enter something and then I still don't had this box. It only showed up after I removed the autocomplete prevention from the input. So for me it seems to work as intended.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: The spec is ugly. I don't know why anyone would want to create invalid xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue on a custom autocomplete control, and fix it by adding `aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false"` to my input field:

You can keep your field ID, and other attributes `autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"`

```
<input id="form-input-id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start typing" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false">
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-autocomplete

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-haspopup

Comment: Thanks! After reading the docs it made sense to try `aria-autocomplete="off"` - as the the docs say that disables suggestions. I tried it with haspopup=false as well but the only combination that works is your answer to set `aria-autocomplete="both"` to turn it on then `aria-haspopup="false"` to turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce the issue either, I think it has something to do with the local cache in your browser. Please try clearing your browser cache: Navigate to `edge://settings/privacy` -> Clear browsing data now -> choose what to clear -> select option `Autofill form data(includes forms and cards)` -> clear now.

In addition, you could also try to turn off `Save and fill basic info` in Edge: Just Navigate to `edge://settings/personalinfo` and check if this work for you.

Comment: Well yeah... but the point is how I can turn it off for web users not myself. Sorry if that wasn't clear.