# What is causing these input boxes juddering (only at chrome mobile) from this simple modal whenever I change the focus of my input?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, css-position

This issue is only can be seen at the mobile Chrome since the mobile keyboard needs to pop up .

Whenever I switch the focus of my input from the 4 input boxes at the modal (whenever I change the place of the cursor inside the input box, like for example when you place a cursor at input box #1 from the input box #3 that is at the bottom of the input box #1), you can see the boxes juddering up and down.

What is causing this issue and how to solve this (no shaking up and down when I change the focus) with those 4 inputs boxes placed at center horizontally and vertically?? Do I have to use Javascript for this to resolve the issue or it can be solved by only css?

The sample code is at https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-rhodes-uyv7wn
and you should test the code at **Chrome mobile** through https://uyv7wn.csb.app/ which is hosted from the codesandbox.

Comment: All major browsers (like firefox, edge, chrome, ...) at PC, it is just working fine (no shaking), but only at Chrome mobile, this strange bug comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the input type from `text` to `search` and now it's working stable without juddering.

Comment: It was due to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988591/prevent-android-keyboard-in-chrome-from-showing-password-management-on-html-inpu